# Neomutt Multi account

Tags: command-line, email, mutt, gmail

I have been using mutt for a while and got it to work pretty well with 2 gmail accounts.
I have 2 macros set to switch from one to the other.

wanting to move to neomutt, the exact configuration is not working anymore.

I can get to my account individually, but I can't swapp from one to the other.

neomuttrc:

```
source ~/.config/neomutt/accounts/account1
folder-hook 'account1' 'source ~/.config/neomutt/accounts/account1'
source ~/.config/neomutt/accounts/account2
folder-hook 'account2' 'source ~/.config/neomutt/accounts/account2'

macro index,pager <f2> '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.config/neomutt/accounts/account1<enter><change-folder>!<enter>'
macro index,pager <f3> '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.config/neomutt/accounts/account2<enter><change-folder>!<enter>'
```

account1:

```
set from = "NAME" 
set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com"

# Imap
set imap_user = "NAMEr@gmail.com" 
set imap_authenticators = "oauthbearer"
set imap_oauth_refresh_command = " ... "
set imap_check_subscribed  
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set postponed = "+[Gmail]/Draft"
set header_cache=~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir = "~/.mutt/cache/bodies"

# Mailbox definition
mailboxes +GMail/INBOX +GMail/MailingList 

# smtp
set smtp_authenticators = "oauthbearer"
set smtp_oauth_refresh_command = "...."
set smtp_url = "smtp://NAME@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set realname = "NAME"
```

I also try to set only the macro, which allows me to chose the account to load. But once I have loaded one, I cannot load the other.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you please try to add `unmailboxes *` at the beginning of each account config file.

Comment: Hi, I did try this. I tried in the macro, and in the account file. Neither fix the prob.

Comment: the config seems fine to me. Come to irc.freenode.net #neomutt discuss it there. You can answer your question here by yourself later.

Comment: Thanks Jindra! the trick was to set folder = "imaps://$imap_user@imap-mail.outlook.com:993"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the trick was to

```
set folder = "imaps://$imap_user@imap.mail.com"
```

having the same folder for the mailboxes was confusing neomutt.